# $\mathbb{Z}_pH$-module

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group with a trivial center. Suppose that $V$ is an elementary abelian subgroup of $G$ and that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that acts faithfully on $V$. Is there any result that guarantees that $V$ is a faithful $\mathbb{Z}_pH$-module?

Since $V$ is an elementary abelian group it will be a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space. Consider $h\ast v$ the faithful action of $H$ on $V$. The most natural way that came to me is to set the $\mathbb{Z}_pH$-module to
$$
(\overline{0}h_1+\ldots+\overline{p-1}h_{p})v=\overline{0}(h_1\ast v)+\ldots+\overline{p-1}(h_{p}\ast v ).
$$

However, I can't show that this module is faithful.

Comment: How does $H$ act on $V$?

Comment: Action is not given, we only know that it exists.

Comment: @ThiagoLuiz, my understanding is that the action of $G$ (and $H$) on $V$ is meant to be by conjugacy.

Comment: @ThiagoLuiz But then why even bother saying $H$ and $V$ are subgroups of a centerless finite solvable group $G$ if that's irrelevant? It's not even said that we're assuming $V$ is normalized.

Comment: It's really irrelevant, since given any action of $G$ on $V$ you can construct a group in which they are both subgroups and the action is via conjugacy.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought this fact was valid general . In the article I am studying, the action is really by conjugation. In the article he says that $H$ acts by conjugation on $V$ and, because of that, we have that $V$ is a faithful $GF(p)H$-modulo.

Answer (score 2):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$In general, you cannot expect $V$ to be a faithful $\mathbb{Z}_{p} H$-module.

Let $G = A_{4}$, and $V$ be its unique Sylow $2$-subgroup. Let $H = \Span{a}$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$. Now $H$ acts faithfully on $V$, but $\mathbb{Z}_{2} H$ does not, as $1 + a + a^{2}$ is in the annihilator.

---

**Addendum**

Somebody more versed than me in these matters will be able to put what I am about to say in proper context.

In the general setting of OP, let $\phi : \Z_{p} H \to \End(V)$ be the homomorphism defining the $\Z_{p} H$-module structure on $V$.

Suppose there is an element $h \in H$ of order $n$ such that the minimal polynomial $m \in \Z_{p}[x]$ of $\phi(h)$ over $\Z_{p}$ is a proper divisor of $x^{n} - 1$. (This will be the case if $\dim(V) < n$, as in the $A_{4}$ example, because $m$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $\phi(h)$, which has degree $\dim(V)$.)

If the degree of $m$ is $d < n$, the elements $1, h, \dots, h^{d}$  are distinct, thus independent in $\Z_{p} H$. It follows that $0 \ne m(h) \in \Z_{p} H$ is an element in the kernel of $\phi$, as $\phi(m(h)) = m(\phi(h)) = 0$, so that the module is not faithful.

Comment: Apologies for the previous incorrect version.

Comment: My dear and old friend here!